# Does anyone know how to make a softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Ok I am new to app development I have tried dozen of codes and even the tried to work with the SDK softkkeyboard sample I have had zero luck once I fix one thing its another and so on...I could never get the softkeyboard to show in graphical view I dont know what else to do..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the soft keyboard exactly as it is -- make sure you get it running first before you try changing anything.  Import it directly into eclipse and then run it.

Another thing you might want to check out is this: http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/checkout
It's the source code for AnySoftKeyboard.  That should give you a good example of how a fully functioning Android keyboard works.

Let me know if you have any problems doing this; I've been developing a soft keyboard for months now so I'm pretty familiar with how touch input works.

Comment: Omg!!! You are who I am looking for!! I am having a terrible time!! Ok I creating a app from the softkeyboard sample in SDK I am taking your advice I changed nothing however the sample I am using is rendering java and html errors it wont even show the keyboard in graphical view nothing works I did download the anysoftkeyboard but that rendered errors as well..I am still trying now do you have an email in which I can email error codes I have been workingo on this for weeks and I have nothing to show...but error codes :(

Comment: This code recieves a error of The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView (Open Class, Show <com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

Comment: Sure, email me at root.lrandroid@gmail.com.  Also, I wouldn't use graphical view for the keyboard -- that view is meant for basic android widgets, unlike the keyboard view.

Comment: Hi lrAndroid, I am trying ADT graphical Layout viewer to render my custom keyboard but no success. Is it even possible for graphical Layout Viewer to render CustomKeyboardView ?

Answer (score 1):

The best article I've found on custom keyboards:

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Author: Maarten Pennings

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: It's too long and complex to add resume. I'll put the author's name so someone could find it in the google's caches after time.